# PHP Can't retrieve cookie on page refresh

Tags: php, session-cookies

Hi I tried saving a cookie like the code below

```
$response = setcookie( "close_pop_up", true, $expiry);
```

and the response was TRUE. I also check the browser for the said cookie and it's existing. But when I refresh the browser and check for the cookie again although its still present in the browser it seems that I can't retrieve this value using the code below

```
isset($_COOKIE['close_pop_up']) && $_COOKIE['close_pop_up']
```

Upon using xdebug the variable `close_pop_up` is not under the $_COOKIE variable. May I know what I'm missing here?

Note: Cookie value still exist on the browser but can't be retrieve.

Comment: Can you write the full code?

Comment: @AXAI sorry false alarm I found the answer. I was missing the "/" after the $expiry

Comment: You should not set cookies using boolean values, you should use 0 or 1 if you don't want to specify an actual value. The "/" after expiry is optional so it shouldn't stop it from working.

Comment: @miknik not sure why but if I remove the "/" the variable for the cookie is not available. Upon checking the browser the "path" for this is set to /ajax. So I'm guessing that this variable will only be available at a url with /ajax as its url. But after appending the "/" as its path I can now see the variable under the $_COOKIE global

Comment: Your guess is entirely correct. If you dont include a path parameter then the it is set to whatever the current path is.